# How can I consider default data for IQueryable<className>

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have many IQueryable on my code, and sometimes I need to return data as nothing.
I don't want to return null as data, because I can't handle on client side

Also I test something like this, but didn't get result

```
IQueryable<className> obj=new IQueryable<className>();
```

Comment: Have you considered `IQueryable<className> obj = Enumerable.Empty<className>().AsQueryable()`

Comment: @Innat3 Thanks, this is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am used to use `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` when I need to return empty enumerables. In the same way you may return an empty IEnumerable as IQueryable;

```
Enumerable.Empty<className>().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's what I want, waiting to accept it after 8minutes :)